# Why is GNU Screen not showing the bottom window caption after split?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

Recently, screen has been failing to show the bottom region's caption after split:

[image: /opt/local/bin/screen]

I am on OS X 10.6 and this is the MacPorts package. Apple's screen at /usr/bin/screen does not have this problem:

[image: /usr/bin/screen]

What's going on? I haven't changed my [.screenrc](http://gist.github.com/559678) anytime recently, and it would be nice to fix this problem without having to recompile screen with debugging flags and go stepping through it with `gdb`.

(btw I am using the MacPorts package because it is compiled with the 256-color option, which I like to have for `vim`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the [vertical split patch](http://fungi.yuggoth.org/vsp4s/) notes:

```
doesn't play nicely with captions (using caption string '' at least hides some
of the unpleasantness)
```

It appears that the MacPorts package now applies the vertical split patch by default, whereas it was offered as a variant the last time I installed it.

Solution: remove the vertical split patch from the port file:

```
diff --git a/Portfile b/Portfile
index 78e3a0b..37ee4d1 100644
--- a/Portfile
+++ b/Portfile
@@ -30,7 +30,7 @@ distfiles-append 18:encoding
 checksums       ${distname}${extract.suffix} md5 8506fd205028a96c741e4037de6e3c42 \
                 18 md5 e5c53546a5c4968bd7e807c88e6b2198 \
                 vproc_priv.h md5 50800817fa688e7e6ae379cd599f15ca
-patchfiles      patch-maxargs patch-windowsize patch-wrp_vertical_split patch-Makefile.in
+patchfiles      patch-maxargs patch-windowsize patch-Makefile.in
 depends_lib     port:ncurses

 extract.only    ${distname}${extract.suffix}
```